# Blob access control

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am designing a storage using azure blob storage. In a container, how to do access control between different blobs?

For example, under container "images", there are 2 blobs: design1/logo.png and design2/logo.png. How to make the access to design1/ and design2/ are exclusively?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to configure the access permissions from RBAC?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal

Comment: I don't think this would work because the lowest level RBAC works is at blob container level and not blob level which is what OP is looking for. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#resource-scope.